# Make a grid of images, then rotate and crop it

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, image-processing

So I have a few thousand thumbnails that I want to stitch together in a slightly tilted grid. I figure that's not going to be the most obvious thing in the world to understand so here's an artists impression of the final output, sans images.

[image]

I've been using ImageMagick so far to create the 17×8 grid. It's simple enough but here's a version with the rose dummy image that will display to screen:

```
montage -mode concatenate $(printf 'rose: %.0s' {1..136}) -resize 100x80 -tile 17x out.jpg
```

[image: roses]

But now I want to rotate and crop. If I chuck `-rotate 1.5`, each image is rotated separately. If I save it and then rotate I compound compression artefacts and lose quality. How do I rotate and crop this grid in the same command?

I'll happily take an alternative to ImageMagick but this has to be command-line as it's going to run on a regular basis on a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well You can pipe things around as BMPs. I think this is as close to lossless as I'm going to get.

```
montage -mode concatenate $(printf 'rose: %.0s' {1..136}) -resize 100x80 -tile 17x bmp:-\
| convert bmp:- -distort SRT 1.5 -crop 1500x500+100+14 out-rotated.jpg
```

[image]

Though I'll happily take a version that can do this in one command.