# How to merge images in a single PDF or image file

Tags: command-line, image-processing

I have some images which I want to merge. By this I mean that if I have 5 images, I want to arrange them in this way:

[image: tiling layout]

I want to do this using a command so that I can use a Bash script for it. For example the command could be like this:

```
foo image1 image2 image3 image4 image5
```

I have lots of images so the command should be able to process a large number of files.

The output can be PDF or even in image format.

Comment: Are they all the same size?

Comment: @Tim yes they are on the same size. I have 29 chart which I want to put them all near each other in one pdf or png file

Comment: @Tim how to vote your edit? :)

Comment: Oh no, not posisble :) but thanks. I've got quite quick on inkscape, it only took a few minutes!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See the `montage` command from `imagemagick` (`sudo apt-get install imagemagick`).

```
montage -geometry 250x250+0+0 image1.png image2.png out.png
```

This will resize each image (to 250px with no deformation) and combine them with no margin.

[More montage examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php).

---

You can also use `convert` (example with wildcards):

```
convert -append pixpixp-*.jpg newpix.jpg
```

Answer (score 6):

I was [doing something similar](https://askubuntu.com/a/506241/449) the other day. Grids are in, it seems. In my case I had a variable number of images being piped into the grid and I just wanted to create a 17 wide image by however many images tall.

```
montage -mode concatenate $(printf 'rose: %.0s' {1..136}) -resize 100x80 -tile 17x output.jpg
```

That just uses 136 rose images to form a 8-tile-high grid. Obviously you'll want to change the `$(...)` group for a list of your input images. And you'll want to set the tile variable to something like `2x` if you just want to set the number of tiles.

In terms of outputting to PDF, you can just change the extension. So you would be looking at something like:

```
montage -mode concatenate $(printf 'rose: %.0s' {1..5}) -tile 2x out.pdf
```